# Writing HTML - img tags when using CDN

Tags: cdn

I'm trying to get into CDN since my image-heavy website is on a shared hosting which spells disaster for visitors.

I've looked into main "disadvantages" of CDN like late caching etc. and I've seen a lot of people advise putting images on separate subdomains or domains and serve them to CDN from there.

So if I'm not mistaken - when using CDN I'm basically putting CDN links for images in the regular img tags on my site and when I update that image on my CDN I have to wait for all the servers under that CDN catch up with the new file?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about "webmaster" stuff, not programming.

Answer (score 0):

Right, it is common practice to create a separate subdomain (e.g. images.yourdomain.com) for your images. This domain will then point to the CDN while your standard domain (www.yourdomain.com) will still point to your web server.
It will be a one-time effort to change your images to the new subdomain (e.g. images.yourdomain.com/img1.jpg). No matter what CDN (or no CDN at all) you are using, you can always point that subdomain to the service you want. You then don't need to touch it again.